# how to delete custom data which are related to schema definition?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am planning to use Microsoft Graph API schema extension for user and groups. I am going to add custom data to user with schema extension property. How can I delete that schema extension custom data from user if it is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only delete a schema extension if the current state is `InDevelopment`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs):

> Only the app that created the schema extension (owner app) can delete the schema extension definition, and only when the extension is in the InDevelopment state. Deleting a schema extension definition does not affect accessing custom data that has been added to resource instances based on that definition.

Once it is out of development, you can only set the value to `null`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups#4-add-update-or-remove-custom-data-in-an-existing-group):

> You can also remove custom data added to a resource instance by setting the corresponding extension property to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for this Marc! Can we bulk update a custom data property for different users at a time.

Comment: Please also let me know if we can have Nested complex data for same.